# Ajuda com lógica no SELECT

Tags: php, sql

Tenho um script de "matchmaking" (como se fosse um jogo).
Ele verifica a cada 3 segundos uma tabela, para ver se tem 10 jogadores que não estão jogando. 
Só que eu preciso verificar também se dentre esses 10 jogadores, um deles sou eu.

O select tá assim

```
$busca_db_qtd = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT ativo, gamemode, playing, id_user FROM users_buscando WHERE ativo = '1' and gamemode = '$gamemode' and playing = '0' and reservados = '0' LIMIT 10");
```

Eu preciso verificar se nesses 10 jogadores, um deles tem o meu id. Como eu posso fazer isso, sem ter que fazer um while no php e utilizar muito processamento (eu acho que utiliza né) ?

Comment: Iterar 10 registros não parece ser algo que vai utilizar muito processamento. O próprio jogador que tá mandando a consulta não deveria aparecer nesse resultado? Se sim, você pode restringir a query fazendo `id_user!=$id`, por exemplo.

Comment: Foi o que eu fiz Joao; :)

Answer (score 0):

Tenta colocar os Ids jogadores que encontras ao correr o script de macthmaking em um array $array jogadores.

```
array_push($array, $jogador->id);
```

Depois basta verificares o array para duplicados.

```
function has_dupes($array) {
$dupe_array = array();
foreach ($array as $val) {
    if (++$dupe_array[$val] > 1) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
}
```

Função "function has_dupes" encontrada em [Link para source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145607/php-check-if-an-array-has-duplicates) por @Mike Sherov